# How to get raw value of `content-type` header in Akka Http?

Tags: scala, akka-http, spray

I am migrating from code spray (version: `1.3.4`) to akka-http (version: `10.0.13`).

We have an existing clients they send `Content-Type` like `application/vnd.awesome.value; mykey="custom/custom"`

Following code works fine in `spray` but in `akka-http` parameter (`mykey`) is stripped off

```
request.header[`Content-Type`].map { header =>
  // HERE PARAMS IS EMPTY MAP
  val myKeyValue = header.contentType.mediaType.params.get("mykey").map(_.replace("\"", ""))
  myKeyValue.flatMap(_.toMediaType).getOrElse(header.contentType.mediaType)
}.getOrElse(defaultMediaType)
```

*StringToMediaTypeConversion.scala*

```
val customMediaTypes: List[MediaType] = ???
implicit class StringToMediaType(private val str: String) extends AnyVal {
  private def parseMediaType(input: String): Option[MediaType] = MediaType.parse(input).fold(_ => None, Some(_))
  private def isSupportedType(mediaType: MediaType): Boolean = customMediaTypes.contains(mediaType)
  private def extractMediaTypeParamIfExists(mediaType: MediaType): Option[MediaType] = mediaType.params.get("mykey") match {
    case Some(value) => parseMediaType(value)
    case None        => Some(mediaType)
  }

  def toMediaType: Option[MediaType] = parseMediaType(str).flatMap(extractMediaTypeParamIfExists).filter(isSupportedType)

}
```

Following unit test is working is passing

```
val customMediaType: Option[MediaType] = """application/vnd.awesome.value; mykey="custom/custom""""".toMediaType
customMediaType should not be None
customMediaType.get.mainType shouldBe "custom"
customMediaType.get.subType shouldBe "custom"
```

Any help is appreciated.

How to extract raw value? or How to extract param value of media type?

Comment: Perhaps you need [headerValueByName](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/header-directives/headerValueByName.html)

Comment: I can not use `headerValueByName` directive because I have to extract multiple headers from the request and do kind of some massage, so in my case ideal to extract request object and do the needful, moreover `content-type` header is not normal header so it wont work with this approach. `Content-Type` header is part of `HttpEntity`

Answer (score 0):

I was registering custom media types as specified in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/http-model.html), if I remove it I am seeing expected behaviour.